# Find closed form $f(x)$ with given limiting behavior?

Tags: limits

Consider the following limit

$$\lim_{x\to 1^-}\frac{f(x)}{\prod_{i=1}^\infty(1-x^i)}=1$$

How to find a function $f(x)$, without making use of the product symbol, such that it satisfies the above equation? Thanks for any suggestion!

PS:

I figured out that $\frac{1}{\Gamma(\frac{1}{1-x})}$ falls off quicker than a valid $f(x)$. Therefore, I expect the result to fall off slower than $(1-x)^{\frac{1}{1-x}}$.

Comment: @Winther I don't see how to do that. Plugging $i(1-x)$ into the product gives "Infinity" times "Zero". Could you elaborate, and maybe give an example?

Comment: Yes I missed that the product was infinite. It would only work for a finite product. btw you can always cheat and say $f(x) = (x;x)_\infty$. The product here is known as the Pockhammer product, see e.g.  http://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-PochhammerSymbol.html

Comment: Yes, with this I agree. Thank you for the link! Turns out, this product even has an own name: the Euler function http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerFunction.html